# What is a rough estimate of CO₂ saturation for high-yield or high growth rate plants?

Tags: plant-physiology, respiration

Naturally, plants have individual photosynthesis capacities, but it would still be interesting to get a general picture of CO<sub>2</sub> saturation levels for some common cultures. Where lies the optimal yield, growth rate, etc compared to the 0.04% in the atmosphere? **What is this specific field of research called?**

My first assessment is that there is no saturation level for individual plants, that each plant consumes CO<sub>2</sub> according to its species' respiration level, and culture density is adapted to the species and practical circumstances such as the greenhouse construction. Is there a field of expertise in planning greenhouse constructions, and if so, what is it called?

It seems to me plants have already or can be genetically modified for heightened respiration. I'm not familiar with this field, **further reading would be appreciated**.

**Would plants genetically modified for heightened respiration require nightly venting/oxygen infusion to support it?**

**Are there examples of cultures treated as respiration machines that are completely optimized for the capacity of their DNA?**

Comment: I am a horticultural consultant for 36 years. I can add that in some enclosed greenhouse situations, growers will artificially increase atmospheric CO₂ in the greenhouse to 1000-1200 PPM, about 3 times normal ambient CO₂.

Comment: Related: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/26231/can-plants-grow-under-extreme-1-carbon-dioxide-concentrations