# "CO2 is plant food" - What is the actual effect of increased CO2 on plant growth?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, photosynthesis

A frequent talking point by global warming deniers is that CO<sub>2</sub> in the atmosphere is actually beneficial because "CO<sub>2</sub> is plant food". I'm a non biologist trying to figure out under what circumstances this is actually true.

Here are my thoughts so far:

- Plant growth is more or less governed by Liebig's law of the minimum - the plant needs sunlight, CO<sub>2</sub>, water, nutrients in a certain composition, whatever is lacking limits growth
- In addition to it's role in photosynthesis, water is needed to transport nutrients from the soil, so dry conditions can limit effective nutrient availability
- The energy needed to assimilate CO<sub>2</sub>-carbon is independent of the CO<sub>2</sub> concentration
- The rate of photosynthesis is (within the limits given by energy etc.) governed by CO<sub>2</sub> concentration and active plant matter
- photosynthesis only works in a more or less narrow temperature band

From this, it follows that a higher CO<sub>2</sub> concentration in air will boost plant growth only if everything else (light, water, nutrients) is abundant.

So I have two interconnecteed questions:

- How wrong is my simplistic view, does my conclusion hold?
- What do we actually observe in the wild or in experiments?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/681/3340

Comment: Definitly helpful. Need some time to read linked papers in the answers over there.

Comment: @mart In brief: High CO2: Toxic effect. Photosynth rate drop.  Stomata closes.  

Medium CO2: Optimum photosynth.  

Low CO2: photosynth rate drastic fall in C3. in C4 plant, fall not so drastic. 

Very Low CO2: C3 stop photosynth, enter "photorespiration". C4 very low rate photosynth.